# Fill_between Matplotlib when data is negative

Tags: python, matplotlib

let's say I have a `df` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-50,-44,-39,-35,-32,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26],
                  'B': [-46,-49,-52,-53,-52,-49,-46,-44,-43,-42]})
```

What I'm simply trying to do is fill the areas below columns `A` and `B` when plotting them with Matplotlib. I'm aware of the function `fill_between` and the following code would work fine, if the data was positive:

```
plt.plot(z.index, z['A'], color='red')
plt.plot(z.index, z['B'], color='blue')
plt.fill_between(x=z.index,y1=z['A'], color='red', alpha=0.25)
plt.fill_between(x=z.index,y1=z['B'], color='blue', alpha=0.25)
```

However, as the data is negative, in this instance the above code fills the area ABOVE the plotted lines. I just want to the filled area to be below the data, regardless of whether it's positive or negative as the actual data I'm working with can be either/or, and will often sometimes centre around 0, i.e. half the data could be positive the other half negative.

Can anyone suggest how to get this to just fill below? Cheers

Comment: How about `plt.plot(z.index, z['A'], color='red'); plt.plot(z.index, z['B'], color='blue');
y_min = min(z['A'] + z['B'] + [0]);
plt.fill_between(x=z.index, y1=y_min, y2=z['A'], color='red', alpha=0.25);
plt.fill_between(x=z.index, y1=y_min, y2=z['B'], color='blue', alpha=0.25)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `y2` paramenter in `fill_between` is 0 by default. If you want to have the fill below, you can change it `y2` to be minimum of the y axis:

```
z = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-50,-44,-39,-35,-32,-30,-29,-28,-27,-26],
                  'B': [-46,-49,-52,-53,-52,-49,-46,-44,-43,-42]})

plt.plot(z.index, z['A'], color='red')
plt.plot(z.index, z['B'], color='blue')

ymin = plt.gca().get_ylim()[0]

plt.fill_between(x=z.index,y1=z['A'], y2=ymin, color='red', alpha=0.25)
plt.fill_between(x=z.index,y1=z['B'], y2=ymin,  color='blue', alpha=0.25)
```

[image]